# An equation upon 2 matrices which carries out matrix multiplication on rows

Tags: matrices, vector-spaces, tensors

This may not be the best way to start (but please stick with me I'll explain more).

I am relatively inexperienced in linear algebra and unfamiliar with tensors (I beleive that's the right term, an 'n-dimensional array' in programming terms, I'm primarily a programmer).

I need a function (or some alternative method of using my inputs to produce the output) of doing the following:

I have 2 matrices, A, a GxP matrix and B, a GxQ matrix.

$A:
\begin{bmatrix}
a_{1,1}&a_{1,2}&\dots \\ a_{2,1}&a_{2,2}&\dots \\ a_{3,1}&a_{3,2}&\dots \\ \vdots&\vdots&\ddots \\
\end{bmatrix}
$op $B:
\begin{bmatrix}
b_{1,1}&b_{1,2}&b_{1,3}&\dots \\ b_{2,1}&b_{2,2}&b_{2,3}&\dots \\ b_{3,1}&b_{3,2}&b_{3,3}&\dots \\ \vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\ddots \\
\end{bmatrix}
$ = $
C:\begin{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}
a_1^T\cdot b_1
\end{bmatrix} 
\begin{bmatrix}
a_2^T\cdot b_2
\end{bmatrix}  \dots 
\begin{bmatrix}
a_G^T\cdot b_G
\end{bmatrix} \end{bmatrix} $

$ = C:
\begin{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}
a_{1,1}\cdot b_{1,1}&a_{1,1}\cdot b_{1,2}&\dots \\
a_{1,2}\cdot b_{1,1}&a_{1,2}\cdot b_{1,2}&\dots \\
\vdots&\vdots&\ddots \\
\end{bmatrix}\dots\end{bmatrix}$

($a_1^T\cdot b_1$ being the matrix multiplication of the column vector $a_1^T$ ($[a_{1,1},a_{1,2},\dots,a_{1,P}]^T$) (transpose ($^T$) of the row vector $a_1$) with the row vector $b_1$ ($[b_{1,1},b_{1,2},\dots,b_{1,Q}]$).

$a_1^T\cdot b_1 = \begin{bmatrix}
a_{1,1}b_{1,1}&a_{1,1}b_{1,2}&\dots\\
a_{1,2}b_{1,1}&a_{1,2}b_{1,2}&\dots\\
\vdots&\vdots&\ddots\\
\end{bmatrix} $

Effectively making a 3 dimensional tensor (I beleive this is correct terminology, please correct if I'm wrong) out of layers which equal the matrix multiplication of each of the rows in the 2 original matrices.

I have been stuck on this for quite a while, I am trying to learn more about the topic, but any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What you're saying here doesn't make sense. The dot products must be between two vectors of the same length. The only dimension the two matrices have in common is $G$. So you have to multiply $B^\top$ ($Q\times G$) by $A$ ($G\times P$) and you get a $Q\times P$ matrix for the answer.

Comment: Now we're taking the dot products of the *rows* of $B^\top$ (i.e., the *columns* of $B$) with the *columns* of $A$. These are both $G$-dimensional vectors.

Comment: @TedShifrin I messed it up, I've changed it to matrix multiplication (basically this https://imgur.com/a/cVIZ4UH), I apologise, basically wrote most of it in reverse by mistake.

Comment: @TedShifrin I would add, feel free to edit my question if I have made mistakes in terminology, I would really appreciate it, would help me learn.

Comment: It *is* matrix product, as I said originally. But it's $B^\top A$. This is a $Q\times P$ matrix whose $ij$ entry is the dot product of the $i$th column of $B$ with the $i$th column of $A$. This is a number. Now, if you're trying to multiply element by element, that has nothing to do with dot product; the "outer" (or tensor) product of vectors $v\otimes w$ is a totally different thing. So now I'm lost. Are you saying that the fact that $G$ matches in your two matrices is irrelevant?

Comment: I will just take a while to consider what you have said and my problem.